# How to write a configurable Java variable creation

Tags: java

A new java component that is suppose to send along a list of pre-define variable to external party. User will then able to define which variable (a fixed set of variable) they want to send via a xml property file

Problem is: The pre-define variable is inside a class, and have business logic together with it, which i can't change or tap into (part of external api). eg as follow:

```
public class DataColumn implement java.io.Serializable{
    public static final String _actionID = "ActionID";
    public static final String _actionName = "ActionName";
    public static final String _actionDesc = "ActionDescription";
    public static final DataColumn ActionDesc = new DataColumn (_actionDesc);
    public static final DataColumn ActionID = new DataColumn (_actionID);
    public static final DataColumn ActionName = new DataColumn (_actionName);

    ....and about 100 other variale more

    protected WebMediaReportColumn(java.lang.String value) {
       _value_ = value;
       _table_.put(_value_,this);
    } 
}
```

user will define in the xml file like following:

```
<interface>
    <fields isRequired="true">
        <field>ActionID</field>
        <field>ActionName</field>
        <field>ActionDescription</field>
     </fields>
</interface>
```

In order to set which variable to send across, the code looks like following:

```
interface.setColumns(new DataColumn[] { 
    DataColumn.ActionID, DataColumn.ActionName, DataColumn.ActionDesc
    }
);
```

Question is: how best to write a program that can base on what the user define in a property file, and create the Datacolumn[] Array accordingly?  **Without** using If else block which is too long and hard to maintain.

Comment: Is that right ? You have an array of type DataColumn[] containing strings

Comment: The code doesn't compile. Show us what you REALLY have.

Comment: @BrianAgnew  Sorry for the wrong code just now, DataColumn[] cannot keep String array.

Comment: What is this `_table` variable? It seems to be a Map that could be used to implement a method such as `DataColumn DataColumn.getByValue(value)`. If such a method exist, then use it. Else, construct such a static map by yourself.

Comment: @JBNizet Good idea! but problem is, the constructor is protected. i cant set it outside of this class.

Answer (score 0):

Write all these statements in a property file.

```
actionID = ActionID
actionName = ActionName
actionDesc = ActionDescription
/*... and so on */
```

In your code create an Properties object and load this file into it. Create an String array and populate the values from this properties object.

```
  Properties p = new Properties();
  /*...load the file...*/
  String []columnData = new String[p.keySet().size()];
  int i=0;
  for(Object str : p.keySet()) {
    columnData[i++]=(String)p.getProperty((String)str);
  }

  /*now call the method and pass the array*/ 
  interface.setColumns(columnData);
```

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenient cause, i have post the wrong code just now. please refer to the code again

Comment: Not a big deal. You can use this code mold it lil bit and use it accordingly. Keep it to yuorself for your homework :-)

Comment: Thats strange... i cant see how t modify this code. reason is because the array is new DataColumn[]  <-- where by inside it, is DataColumn.ActionID.  how do i even assign/define DataColumn.ActionID from a xml property file?